# mailkit.net/mimekit.net Get original Message from Multipart/Signed Message

Tags: c#, .net, imap, mailkit, mimekit

I have a Multipart/Signed message and can verify it. Now I need to access the original Message to be able to access the attachments. Is there a way to access the original Message after the Verification happened and how would you do it using mailkit.net/mimekit.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original message body is just the first child of the MultipartSigned part.

I'm presuming here that the multipart/signed part is the toplevel part of the message (which is typically the case):

```
var body = message.Body;

if (body is MultipartSigned signed) {
    // do your verification as you've already done...

    // update 'body' to point to the original message body
    body = signed[0];
}

// process 'body' as if it was the body of the message
```

Comment: But the attachments are flagged inline in this original message body. Outlook detects them as attachments. Do they use heuristics for that or is there a way to parse this original message so attachments are flagged attachment?

Comment: Outlook shows everything that isn't explicitly referenced by the HTML body as an attachment, even if it is marked "inline". You can do the same using an approach similar to my `HtmlPreviewVisitor` that is in the [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/FAQ.md)

Comment: Thanks, so youre the creator of Mimekit.net?

Comment: Yep, I'm the author of MimeKit and MailKit.